# How access specific DOM in React js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get input tags' HTML inner values when submitting a form.

```
private handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
  };
```

When the submit the form, it calls the function `handleSubmit` and it console logs the following.

[image: e]

Under the `form` tag, the first `div` has username value and the second `div` has password value. I would like to acess the two values. I think I should use DOM to do that, but can't be sure if I'm going for the right direction cuz I found some postings saying using DOM is not recommended.

Can anyone explain how I can acheive this?

Comment: On your render method, the input should have a property `value` where you put the current value of that input. So you need an `onChange` property passing a function that will get the value the user is trying to achieve, update it, and your render method will make the change on input

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should update your state as the user enters information, and then access the data from the state. This would also allow you to run any validation on the data prior to it going into the state if you'd like.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: null,
      password: null
    }
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
    this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
  }
  updateState (e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
  submitForm (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" onChange={this.updateState} /><br />
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.updateState} /><br />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The above code does the following:

- Stores default values for `username` and `password`. While this isn't required, it makes the code more readable
- binds `this` to functions that need to access state
- Uses an `updateState()` function that is called `onChange` of the inputs
- `updateState` uses the `name` attribute of the input as the key for the state

You could customize the `updateState()` function to do some validation, before saving to state if you'd like.

#### Excessive Rendering

ReactJS is pretty smart to no re-render the REAL DOM if your `render()` method doesn't actually rely on the state values that were updated; however, if you'd like to prevent ReactJS from even creating the Virtual DOM and comparing, you could utilize the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle hook.

In the particular example above, since render doesn't rely on ANYTHING in state, you could simply add the following method:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevState, nextState) {
  return false;
}
```

That will prevent the render method from EVER re-rendering, which is most likely not going to work in a normal component, thus you could do something like this instead, only re-rendering on values you care about.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(prevState, nextState) {
  if (nextState.email !== prevState.email) {
    return true
  }
  return false;
}
```

#### Demo

https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53689072

Comment: I already have my app working with `onChange`, but my team leader pointed out that using `onChange` on input section is bad practice because it needlessly re-renders the page too much. It re-renders the page whenever you type each character which is too much re-rendering. That's why I'm trying use only `onSubmit` so that I can get the username and password values when submitting the form.

Comment: ReactJS is smart enough to not actually re-render the REAL DOM because your render function doesn't rely on the state values.

Comment: @Jay I'm going to add some clarification to my answer about rendering

Comment: And then there are other events too, like `onBlur` which would update the state only when the input field goes out of focus.

Comment: @AnonymousSB you could also change the  `submitForm` and `updateState` function to arrow functions, eliminating the need for bindings.

Comment: @PredragBeocanin, it's a style choice; however, I like the readability of manually binding the functions that need it, rather than auto-binding all functions by using arrow functions, or mixing arrow functions with non-arrow functions for the sake of auto-binding, which may not be obvious to others who read the code why there is a mix of arrow and non-arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the DOM, once you have the [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) (`event.currentTarget` in your case), you can use the `.elements` property to access a list of child inputs and buttons.

Alternatively, you can use [React refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs) to keep track of the underlying HTML element when it's rendered.

```
render() {
  return ... <input ref={(e) => this._name = e; } ....> ... ;
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  var name = this._name ? this._name.value : '';
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can achieve what you want to

```
class Login extends Component{
   state={ 
     username:"",
     password:""
    }
  onChange = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
  onSubmit = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    // submit whatever is in state from here
    console.log(this.state)
}
    render(){
      return(<div>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} /><br />
      <input type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} /><br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>)
    }
}
```